# Should a reference to a null variable throw exception

Tags: c#, linq, exception

The query below consists of multiple `INNER JOIN` clauses.

The `Student` table has a lot of foreign keys which are substituted by names in the query. I am using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query below. Please note `MarkID` in the `Students` can be `null`. That means `marksGroup.DefaultifEmpty()` may return `null` as well. Therefore if I put only `m` instead of `m != null ? m.MarkName : "-- Not marked --"` in the last line, the code IMO should throw an exception when `m` is null because I am referring to this variable but it didn't. On a example which I build this query on, a compiler thrown exception. Please see the code:

```
var result = from st in dbContext.Students where st.DepartmentID == 17
             join d in dbContext.Departments on st.DepartmentID equals d.DepartmentID
             join sv in dbContext.SoftwareVersions on st.SoftwareVersionID equals sv.SoftwareVersionID
             join stat in dbContext.Statuses on st.StatusID equals stat.StatusID
             join m in dbContext.Marks on st.MarkID equals m.MarkID into marksGroup
             from m in marksGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 student = st.StudentName,
                 department = p.DepartmentName,
                 software = sv.SoftwareVersionName,
                 status = st.StatusName,
                 marked = m != null ? m.MarkName : "-- Not marked --"
             };
```

What am I missing. I am still beginner in terms of **C#** and **LINQ**.

Comment: `[...] if I put only m [...]`. Referencing the object will not throw an exception. However, performing any operation on it, **will throw one**. That is, trying to call a method or a property. For example, `marked = m` shouldn't throw any exception, you are just referencing the object. `marked = m.MarkName`, however, should throw a **NullReferenceException** if `m == null`.

Comment: Do you mean you believe `marked = m` should throw an exception?

Comment: @MatiCicero Thanks Mati. That's explain the difference between me and the example. I've looked at the example code again and the author indeed tried to refer to a property of a null object :) Cheers!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well, I thought it should but I did not know what Mati explained :)

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a LINQ statement against a SQL backend (I assume you have Entity Framework here) the *whole* statement is translated into SQL and executed by the database engine.

So this is what the .Net runtime does:

- Translate the statement (which is an `Expression`) into SQL
- Send the SQL to the database through ADO.Net.
- Receive the SQL result set (essentially an array of rows, where a row is itself an array of values).
- Create objects from these rows.

In your case, the objects to be created can safely be defined by the part

```
select new
{
    student = st.StudentName,
    department = p.DepartmentName,
    software = sv.SoftwareVersionName,
    status = st.StatusName,
    marked = m.MarkName
}
```

The only thing the .Net runtime is concerned with is to create an instance of an anonymous type and set its properties from one row in the result set. In some rows, the value for `marked` may be `null`, so `marked` will set to `null` in that particular object. The .Net runtime is not dealing with a `MarksGroup` object there.

Of course in LINQ to objects this would be totally different. There the null check is absolutely necessary to prevent null object references.